# having issues with this simple code trying to get a value

Tags: wordpress

am just confused why such a small difference can make a big problem.

here is the working code with just digits entered into it.

```
$user_info = get_userdata(70);
  echo 'Username: ' . $user_info->user_login . "\n";
```

this code shows username: sarah

and now same but this time with code inside of it

```
$number = the_author_meta('ID');
echo $number;   // echos   70
$user_info = get_userdata($number);
  echo 'Username: ' . $user_info->user_login . "\n";
```

and with the code below it just shows userame:  thats it.

Comment: Did any of the answers posted help you out?

Answer (score 1):

MAke sure you read your code. At this line:

`$user_info = get_userdata($number);`

You miss a r in the variable $number

Comment: $number = the_author_meta('ID');
echo $number;
$user_info = get_userdata($number);   not working ? how come

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

Replace "the_author_meta" with "get_the_author_meta"

the_author_meta just immediately outputs to the screen the information you're trying to retrieve. That's why it outputs '70'.. If you get rid of the echo in front of it, it'd STILL output that 70.

get_the_author_meta actually returns the value and assigns it to a variable, like you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$aaaaaa = $author_id=$post->post_author;
$user_info = get_userdata($aaaaaa);
  echo 'Username: ' . $user_info->user_login . "\n";
      echo 'User roles: ' . implode(', ', $user_info->roles) . "\n";
      echo 'User ID: ' . $user_info->ID . "\n";

echo get_user_option( 'rc_banned', $user_info->ID);
```